# Como carregar modelos 3D de arquivos "obj" para uma aplicação PyOpenGL?

Tags: python, opengl, blender, pyopengl

Como pegar um ".obj" e importar para o PyOpengl?
ex: pegar um modelo 3D do blender e coloca-lo em uma cena no Pyopengl?

Answer (score 3):

Para importar arquivos gráficos 3D (ex: WaveFront `obj`, [Collada](https://www.khronos.org/collada/), etc.) em uma aplicação [PyOpenGL](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/),
 de forma simples, são necessárias 4 operações:

- Criar uma janela para a aplicação
- Configurar os parâmetros do [OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/)
- Carregar os dados do(s) arquivo(s) para estruturas de dados dentro do programa (e demais componentes da aplicação)
- Criar um *looping* que: a cada passo, transfere os dados para o OpenGL (*display*) e altera as propriedades dos objetos (*update*)

## Modelagem dos Objetos

No [Blender](https://www.blender.org/) (ou qualquer outra ferramenta 3D), os objetos são formados por vários componentes, por exemplo:

- Geometria (vértices, faces, coordenadas UV de texturas, etc.)
- Materiais (difusão, reflexão, transparência, etc.)
- Texturas (imagens, mapas bump, mapas displacement, etc.)

Ao exportar o modelo para um arquivo `obj`, existem várias opções para escolher o quê será exportado (ex: incluir UV, Normais, etc.).

Abaixo, segue uma imagem do menu de opções para exportar um modelo ou objeto  para o formato `obj` no Blender versão 2.76b:

[image: Menu de opções de exportação de arquivos WaveFront obj, do software Blender versão 2.76b]

Quanto maior o número de detalhes exportados, maior é a complexidade de desenvolvimento da aplicação, que precisará tratar esses detalhes.

Exemplo de arquivos gerados:

A imagem abaixo representa um cubo simples (apenas a geometria foi definida):

[image: Cubo simples, apenas a geometria foi definida]

Esse cubo, ao ser exportado, gera o seguinte arquivo `obj`:

```
# Blender v2.76 (sub 0) OBJ File: ''
# www.blender.org
o Cube
v 1.000000 0.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 0.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 0.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 0.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 2.000000 -0.999999
v 0.999999 2.000000 1.000001
v -1.000000 2.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 2.000000 -1.000000
s off
f 2 3 4
f 8 7 6
f 5 6 2
f 6 7 3
f 3 7 8
f 1 4 8
f 1 2 4
f 5 8 6
f 1 5 2
f 2 6 3
f 4 3 8
f 5 1 8
```

Já a imagem abaixo, representa um cubo mais complexo, com materiais e iluminação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao ser exportado, esse cubo gera 2 arquivos:

Um arquivo `obj` com a definição da geometria:

```
# Blender v2.76 (sub 0) OBJ File: ''
# www.blender.org
mtllib cubo.mtl
o Cube
v 1.000000 0.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 0.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 0.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 0.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 2.000000 -0.999999
v 0.999999 2.000000 1.000001
v -1.000000 2.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 2.000000 -1.000000
vt 0.666467 0.333134
vt 0.333533 0.333134
vt 0.333533 0.000200
vt 0.666467 0.000200
vt 0.333134 0.333133
vt 0.000200 0.333134
vt 0.000200 0.000200
vt 0.333133 0.000200
vt 0.333134 0.333533
vt 0.333133 0.666467
vt 0.000200 0.666467
vt 0.000200 0.333533
vt 0.333134 0.666866
vt 0.333133 0.999800
vt 0.000200 0.999800
vt 0.000200 0.666866
vt 0.666867 0.333134
vt 0.666867 0.000200
vt 0.999800 0.000200
vt 0.999800 0.333134
vt 0.666467 0.333533
vt 0.666467 0.666467
vt 0.333533 0.666467
vt 0.333533 0.333533
vn 0.000000 -1.000000 0.000000
vn 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
vn 1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
vn -0.000000 -0.000000 1.000000
vn -1.000000 -0.000000 -0.000000
vn 0.000000 0.000000 -1.000000
usemtl Material.001
s off
f 1/1/1 2/2/1 3/3/1 4/4/1
f 5/5/2 8/6/2 7/7/2 6/8/2
f 1/9/3 5/10/3 6/11/3 2/12/3
f 2/13/4 6/14/4 7/15/4 3/16/4
f 3/17/5 7/18/5 8/19/5 4/20/5
f 5/21/6 1/22/6 4/23/6 8/24/6
```

E um (ou mais) arquivos `mtl`, com as bibliotecas de materiais:

```
# Blender MTL File: 'cubo.blend'
# Material Count: 2

newmtl Material.001
Ns 96.078431
Ka 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
Kd 0.640000 0.640000 0.640000
Ks 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
Ke 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Ni 1.000000
d 1.000000
illum 2
```

## Janela da Aplicação

Antes de iniciar o OpenGL, é necessário criar um **contexto de execução** ("janela" da aplicação) onde irá ocorrer a renderização da cena.

Abaixo, seguem quatro exemplos de bibliotecas que gerenciam esse contexto (mas existem outras):

- [pygame](http://www.pygame.org/) (já tem suporte para carga de arquivos `obj`)
- [pyglet](http://www.pyglet.org/) (já tem suporte para carga de arquivos `obj` com o pacote [PyWavefront](https://github.com/greenmoss/PyWavefront))
- [FreeGLUT](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/) (mais simples, porém, mais fácil) com [PyGLUT](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyglut/1.0.0)
- [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/) (tem mais recursos, mas é mais complexa) com  [PyGLFW](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyglfw/0.1.0)

E abaixo, um trecho de código para iniciar uma janela com a biblioteca GLFW:

```
import pyglfw.pyglfw as glfw
import OpenGL.GL as GL

# Inicializa o GLFW
if (not(glfw.init())):
      raise Exception("Impossivel criar a janela GLFW!!!!")

# Configura os parâmetros da janela que será criada
glfw.Window.hint(client_api=glfw.Window.OPENGL_API)
glfw.Window.hint(resizable=False)
glfw.Window.hint(visible=False)

# Cria a janela e guarda uma referência a ela
winHandle = glfw.Window(LARGURA_JANELA, ALTURA_JANELA, "Teste OpenGL")
if (winHandle == 0):
    raise Exception("Impossivel criar a janela!!!")

# Seta o contexto corrente para OpenGL
winHandle.make_current()

#--------------------------------------------------------
# Aqui, deve-se configurar todos os parâmetros do OpenGL
# e carregar os arquivos necessários para a aplicação.
#--------------------------------------------------------

# Tempo de atualização da janela.
# Quanto menor, mais rápido
winHandle.swap_interval(2)

# Abre a janela
winHandle.show()
```

## Configuração do OpenGL

A configuração do OpenGL depende muito da versão utilizada e do tipo de aplicação que será desenvolvido.

Exemplo de configurações:

```
# Configura o tamanho do Viewport
GL.glViewport(0, 0, LARGURA_JANELA, ALTURA_JANELA)

# Seta a cor preta como cor de fundo
GL.glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
```

## Carga de Arquivos

Caso você utilize o pacote pyglet (com PyWavefront) ou pygame, o ideal é utilizar as funções disponíveis para fazer a carga dos arquivos `obj`.

Caso você opte por utilizar uma biblioteca que **não** dá suporte para a leitura de arquivos `obj`,
você pode montar um módulo para abrir o arquivo (ex: `open('arquivo.obj', 'r')`), e ler os dados, conforme o padrão:

[Wikipedia - Wavefront .obj file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file)

[Especificação OBJ](http://www.martinreddy.net/gfx/3d/OBJ.spec)

Além dos arquivos com os modelos, você precisará carregar também:

- as texturas e outras imagens, que podem ser carregadas com a biblioteca [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/)
- os [shaders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shader) (caso você utilize)
- demais arquivos da aplicação

Caso você utilize shaders na aplicação, uma dica é você instalar uma biblioteca para efetuar cálculos 3D com vetores e matrizes, como, por exemplo, a **[Pyrr](https://github.com/adamlwgriffiths/Pyrr)**.

E, por último:

## Looping Principal

No looping principal, você irá mover os objetos, iluminação, etc.

Abaixo, segue um exemplo desse looping (GLFW):

```
# Enquanto não houver uma solicitação para fechar a janela
while(not(winHandle.should_close)):
    # Limpa a tela
    GL.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)

    # Renderiza a cena - nesta função, você irá desenvolver o
    # processo que alimenta o opengl com os dados da cena (ex: modelos,
    # imagens, texturas, etc.)
    render()

    # Apresenta a cena no dispositivo de saída
    winHandle.swap_buffers()

    # Atualiza estado da aplicação - nesta função, você
    # aplica a lógica do programa  (ex: move objetos, 
    # efetua cálculos de inteligência artificial, 
    # transfere dados, etc.)
    update()

    # Processa eventos do sistema
    glfw.poll_events()
```

[Wikipedia - Índice - Categoria: Computação gráfica](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categoria:Computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_gr%C3%A1fica)
(sugestão: consultar a versão em inglês também)

**Atualização:**

Mais referências de programação com PyOpenGL:

[Modern OpenGL tutorial (python) - Nicolas P. Rougier](http://www.labri.fr/perso/nrougier/teaching/opengl/)

[OpenGLContext Python Tutorials](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/context/tutorials/)

[2D graphics rendering tutorial with PyOpenGL - Cyrille Rossant, PhD](http://cyrille.rossant.net/2d-graphics-rendering-tutorial-with-pyopengl/)

[Códigos para Download - Jestermons Python Pitstop](http://jestermon.weebly.com/pygame.html)

[3D PROGRAMMING IN PYTHON – PART 1](https://greendalecs.wordpress.com/2012/04/21/3d-programming-in-python-part-1/) (versão mais antiga do OpenGL, sem uso de VBO)